# Top-level .mak file for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build-process, build-automation, makefile

I've inherited a body of Visual C++ source that consists of about a dozen sub-projects.  One of these is an empty "MakeAll" project that depends on all the others, so I can build the entire project by setting the MakeAll project active and selecting "Build All."

I'd like to automate this process, and coming from a linux environment, my instinct was to generate a Makefile and build from the command line.  The IDE will generate `.mak` files for each of the sub-projects, but not for the top-level MakeAll.  (I'm assuming this is because it contains nothing but dependencies.)

The linux answer would be a Makefile that simply descends into each of the sub-projects and executes `make` in each one.  But a quick look at the `.mak` files showed that each wants to be told which of several configurations to use -- and apparently some use Debug, some use Release, and some use configurations concocted by a previous developer.

What's the accepted way to build a set of projects like this from the command line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use make - if you have everything as solution files (.sln) then you can automate the build by using [the msbuild tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx):

```
msbuild solution.sln
```

Also, why do you have a "MakeAll" project? Visual Studio doesn't require this kind of hackery, just do a "build all" and it will build everything satisfying dependancies just like a typical "make all" rule would.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  The project generates several individual executables and other pieces, and there are several disjoint dependency trees.  Can I still get away w/o a MakeAll?

Comment: Visual Studio handles the dependancies much like make would. You can specify dependacies between projects by (from memory) right click -> dependancies

Comment: Hmmm ... might be worth upgrading from MS VS6 just for the tools.  Best advice I've gotten from a troll-free number - thanks aagin!!

Comment: You can do much the same trick with VS6, as I recall you basically do something like: msdev.exe solution.sln - the msdev.exe being the same as the visual studio app